# getting Type Error in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, rhomobile

In my rhomobile application am using ajax call, when I made a request am getting Type Error in console am not getting the where I did mistake.

Here is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_login").on("click",function(){
        alert("hi");
        var username = $('#txt_username').val();
        var password = $('#txt_password').val();
        alert(username+","+password)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'app/Login/login_request',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {username: $('#txt_username'),
                    password: $('#txt_password')
                    },
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" id="txt_username">
<input type="password" id="txt_password">
<input id="btn_login" type="submit">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_login").on("click",function(){
        //alert("hi");
        var username = $('#txt_username').val();
        var password = $('#txt_password').val();
        //alert(username+","+password)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'app/Login/login_request',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {username: username,password: password},
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your ajax call should be:

```
$("#btn_login").on("click",function(){
        alert("hi");
        var username = $('#txt_username').val();
        var password = $('#txt_password').val();
        console.log(username+","+password)

        $.ajax({
            url: 'app/Login/login_request',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {username: username ,
                    password: password 
                    },
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

    });
```

Because you are sending the Object not the value. And use Console.log to debug.

Comment: Wilfredo P thanks for the reply, it is working now after adding 'data: {username: username, password: password}'